# Glassfish and ActiveMQ XATransactions

Tags: glassfish, jms, activemq-classic, distributed-transactions

I'm using

- Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 ((v2.1 Patch06)(9.1_02 Patch12))
- activemq-rar-5.4.2-fuse-02-00.rar
- XATransaction for activemq-rar

I experience the exception below and I suspect that it is because activemqra cannot get hold of the activemq connection after a XATransaction is started.
I would have expected that activemqra would roll back the transaction in this case.

Currently the started transaction hangs in Glassfish untill its timed out. This is especially bad when a db transaction is part of the XATransaction 
because then the db connection is unavailable.

I have no idea about what to do, so I dont get hanging transactions?

Any help or comments are welcome.

Best regards Trym

```
[#|2011-07-14T15:24:50.946+0200|INFO|sunappserver2.1| javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.mdb |_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=p: mdb-threadpool; w: 6;|javax.ejb.EJBException javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.; 
nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: 
Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [commit one phase] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: 
Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [commit one phase] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.distributedtx.J2EETransactionManagerImpl.commit(J2EETransactionManagerImpl.java:1029)
    at com.sun.enterprise.distributedtx.J2EETransactionManagerOpt.commit(J2EETransactionManagerOpt.java:398)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:3826)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:3605)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDeliveryInternal(MessageBeanContainer.java:1226)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanContainer.java:1197)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:139)
    at $Proxy65.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.MessageEndpointProxy$MessageEndpointAlive.afterDelivery(MessageEndpointProxy.java:128)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.MessageEndpointProxy.afterDelivery(MessageEndpointProxy.java:69)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ServerSessionImpl.afterDelivery(ServerSessionImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.run(ActiveMQSession.java:897)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ServerSessionImpl.run(ServerSessionImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:77)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:555)
javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [commit one phase] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:3837)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:3605)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDeliveryInternal(MessageBeanContainer.java:1226)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanContainer.java:1197)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:139)
    at $Proxy65.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.MessageEndpointProxy$MessageEndpointAlive.afterDelivery(MessageEndpointProxy.java:128)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.MessageEndpointProxy.afterDelivery(MessageEndpointProxy.java:69)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ServerSessionImpl.afterDelivery(ServerSessionImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.run(ActiveMQSession.java:897)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ServerSessionImpl.run(ServerSessionImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:77)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:555)
|#]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug on Glassfish. It tries to close a thread that is already closed. There's a patch to correct this issue. 
Take a look at https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1979095.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After reading the oracle forum I'm very much in doubt of how to get the patch and if the patch is already part of the Glassfish version v2.1.1 ((v2.1 Patch06)(9.1_02 Patch12)) which I'm using. Can you give me any hints about this or where to look for further information. Thanks in advance. Best regards Trym

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the contents of glassfish/domains/domain1/imq/instances/imqbroker/fs370

this is happening because of some weird corrupted files to persist the queue data... after cleaning this folder, the errors will be gone